# Can PCs swim in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

Some creatures have aquatic speed, but playable classes do not.

**Does this imply that PCs cannot swim**? Or does swimming count as difficult terrain? Or do they just have the same speed? Or is an athletics check necessary for water movement?

Comment: this is a very valid question and I urge other user to vote it up

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, PCs can swim.

[From the 5e SRD in the "Movement" section](http://www.5esrd.com/using-ability-scores/#Climbing_Swimming_and_Crawling):

> **Special Types of Movement**
>
> Movement through dangerous dungeons or wilderness areas often involves more than simply walking. Adventurers might have to climb, crawl, swim, or jump to get where they need to go.
>
> **Climbing, Swimming, and Crawling**
>
> While climbing or swimming, each foot of movement costs 1 extra foot (2 extra feet in difficult terrain), unless a creature has a climbing or swimming speed. At the GM’s option, climbing a slippery vertical surface or one with few handholds requires a successful Strength (Athletics) check. Similarly, gaining any distance in rough water might require a successful Strength (Athletics) check.

Comment: Yes, a player character is assumed to know how to swim, and doesn't need any specific proficiency or training to do so.